# Android Retrofit API usage

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm still beginner on retrofit API for android, im trying to pass a variable into my dynamic url but it adds extra characters to it these characters are "&=".

This is what the endpoint im trying to consume looks like:

https://www.example.com/api/index.php?/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/9392

where "9232" is the id i am trying to pass. However when i use the retrofit library this is what my generated Url looks like:

https://www.example.com/api/index.php?/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/&=9392

Notice the **&=** being attached to the Id im sending

```
// Method that receives id and calls the retrofit API
private void getPlaylist(String id) {
    /*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
    GetPlaylistRetrofitInterface playlistService = PlaylistClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetPlaylistRetrofitInterface.class);

    Call<List<Playlists>> call = playlistService.getPlaylist(id);
    Log.d("URL", "getPlaylist: " + call.request().url());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Playlists>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Playlists>> call, Response<List<Playlists>> response) {
            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            populatePlayList(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Playlists>> call, Throwable throwable) {
            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d("onFailure", "onFailure: " + throwable);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the interface where i am receiving the url id and attaching it to the endpoint

```
public interface GetPlaylistRetrofitInterface {
    @GET("index.php?/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/")
    Call<List<Playlists>> getPlaylist(@Query(value = "") String id);
}
```

I have tried using @Path in my interface

```
public interface GetPlaylistRetrofitInterface {
    @GET("index.php?/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/{id}")
    Call<List<Playlists>> getPlaylist(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

However it made my app crash with this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demoapp.HomeActivity}:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/{id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
            for method GetPlaylistRetrofitInterface.getPlaylist
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Thanks in Advance

Okay so i was able to Fix the issue, I turned out i was trying to pass a query by using @Query to an endpoint which is already a query so this is how i fixed it:

This is my updated GetPlaylistInterface

```
public interface GetPlaylistRetrofitInterface {
    @GET()
    Call<List<Playlists>> getPlaylist(@Url String url);
}
```

This is my updated Get Playlist method

```
private void getPlaylist(String id) {
    myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    /*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
    GetPlaylistRetrofitInterface playlistService = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetPlaylistRetrofitInterface.class);
    Call<List<Playlists>> call = playlistService.getPlaylist(Config.playlist_url+id);
    Log.d("URL", "getPlaylist: " + call.request().url());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Playlists>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Playlists>> call, Response<List<Playlists>> response) {
            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            populatePlayList(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Playlists>> call, Throwable throwable) {
            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d("onFailure", "onFailure: " + throwable);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the config class containing the endpoints:

```
public class Config {
    public static String playlist_url = "index.php?/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/";
    public static String playlist_details_url = "index.php?/Tracks/get/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/";
}
```

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-optional-path-parameters

Comment: I have already tried that, when i did the App crashes and i got this error:                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/{id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

Answer (score 0):

You're using @Query parameter, which has this syntax by default.
What your need is to use **@Path** instead of @Query. Also you need to include name of parameter into your url string.

Your code will look somehow like this:

```
public interface GetPlaylistRetrofitInterface {
@GET("index.php?/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/{id}")
Call<List<Playlists>> getPlaylist(@Path("id") String id);
```

}

Comment: i have already tried that, i made my app crash with this error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/{id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

Answer (score 0):

You almost Have it first You need to use Query Parameter for you query String and Path for url/uri manipulation seems like you had those mixed up now below example should work

```
public interface ApiServices {
@GET("index.php?/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/{id}")
Call<ResponseBody> getTracks(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

EDIT:

You need to only define Interface and call it once. Above is interface and below is how to call it from a functions like your trying to do... its weird you have index.php? are you sure that is needed.

```
  // Method that receives id and calls the retrofit API
private void getPlaylist(String id) {
/*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()


               .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
               .build();
       Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .client(client)
               .baseUrl("https://stepank.com/")
               .build();

       ApiServices service = retrofit.create(ApiServices.class);

       try {


           Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getTracks(id);
           call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                   int result = -1;
                   setRefreshActionButtonState(false);

                   if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                       ///DO STUFF HERE WITH RESPONSE
                }
                                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                   t.printStackTrace();
               }
           });
```

}

Comment: I dont know if im doing this correctly but it makes my app crash with the same error:    `@GET("index.php?/Playlists/getTracks/00978d67f6933af10ec8bd8045f089a4/0673CC13-476A-4786-BF27-13ADD9C44261/{id}")
    Call<List<Playlists>> getPlaylist(@Path("") String QueryStringParameters,@Query("id") String id );`